# three20 Integration error?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, three20

Please help me to resolve this error...

This error has comes up when run on device but when run on simulator than application run smoothly without errors..

I have got this below error...

Please help me

```
    Ld /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MySMSFriend.app/MySMSFriend normal armv7s
    cd "/iTune/SMS Final App/SMS/MySMSFriend"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -arch armv7s -isysroot "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" -L/Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/iTune/SMS Final App/SMS/MySMSFriend/Classes/Start" -F/Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Intermediates/iRealify.build/Debug-iphoneos/iRealify.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MySMSFriend.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -lThree20Core -lThree20Network -lThree20Style /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -lxml2 -framework AVFoundation -framework MessageUI -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -framework AudioToolbox -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -lz -framework CoreLocation -o /Users/vipalpanchal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iRealify-hkospzktmsronzeeoslnvwfniaok/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MySMSFriend.app/MySMSFriend

ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You are not getting this when running the app on a device. You are getting this linker error when building for a device.

Comment: This error comes when installing app on a device